# MySQLSyntaxErrorException : Error while upgrading MySQL version

Tags: mysql

While I was upgrading MySQL version from 5.7.22 to 8.0.18 using connector version 5.1.48, I got following error in a query:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'member on
>   r.user_role_id = member.user_role_id  left join action_permission p
>   on' at line 1

Query is mentioned below:

```
select p.name 
from users u 
    left join user_role r on u.user_role_id = r.user_role_id 
    left join user_role_action_permission member on r.user_role_id = member.user_role_id 
   left join action_permission p on member.permission_id = p.permission_id 
where p.NAME = ? 
and u.USER_ID = ?
```

Help me in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

> **MEMBER**; added in 8.0.17 (reserved); became nonreserved in 8.0.19

Quote. Or upgrade up to 8.0.19.